# VirtualBox on Mac: getting a network connection?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've installed VirtualBox on a Macbook with Mac OS 10.6 and it's running great. Inside the VirtualBox I'm running Ubuntu 10.04. Really impressive setup and install process.

However, there's one problem, which is that Ubuntu has no network connection. And I'm a total newbie to networking.

Could anyone suggest where to start?

Infinite gratitude will be yours :)

Comment: Please help us helping you by showing us your VirtualBox settings, especially those of your virtual machine under "Networking" settings. Also, show us the output of `ifconfig` when run in the Terminal in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Networking should already be set up as a NAT:

[image]

Another choice is setting it up as a Bridged Network, in my screenshot it's pointing to my ethernet, but there should be an interface for your wireless (wlan0 perhaps) this will make your VM act as if it were a computer in your physical network and get local IP Address that will allow you to browse to it from other devices in the network:

[image]

Comment: To add to Sandeep's answer, make sure Ubuntu is actually seeing a network card. `ifconfig` can give you that answer. If I remember right, VitualBox's tools might have something for fixing cases when the guest OS doesn't recognize the host network card.